# .mat dataset in Torch

Tags: dataset, neural-network, mat, conv-neural-network, torch

I am having a bit of trouble in using Torch deep learning tool since I am new to it. I want to run convolutional neural network for my project on Torch. I have dataset in `.mat` format. I have no idea how to use it. I have tried some other datasets, but still couldn't find a way to use my own dataset in their place. I converted `mha` format to `.mat` format via Matlab and now I want to use those images for training in Torch. Help me out please.

I have been following this link:
*[Github: Deep Learning with Torch.ipynb](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb)*

Comment: Please share some code or error messages(if any)

Comment: i have the very basic code to load popular datasets in t7 format. My files are in mat format. I tried converting them in csv since i read somewhere that csv can be used in torch but a single csv file saves only one image. I don't know what to do with it. Help me out please

Comment: Hey i have converted the dataset in t7 format via this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657533/what-is-the-structure-of-torch-dataset
Now i have another question. I want to segment brain tumor using convolutional neural network. Can you help me out by providing me link to any tutorial which is related to segmentation using neural networks? Please i am in dire need of it because i can't find any information related to this anywhere.